# How to copy object wrapped inside the option in anothe object in scala

Tags: scala

I have following structure in Scala -

```
case class SomeObject (name: String, anotherObject: Option[AnotherObject])
case class AnotherObject (value1: Array[String], value2: String, value3: String)
```

Now I want to make copy of the SomeObject which is already instantiated like below.

```
SomeObject.copy(anotherObject = SomeObject.anotherObject.copy
                                (value3 = <SomeAnotherValue>))
```

This is not working, please suggest the possible solution for this.

Comment: Well, `anotherObject` is an **Option**, which does not have a `copy` method. I think that you want to change the inner value _(Assuming `AnotherObject` is also a `case class`)_, only if `anotherObject` exists _(meaning it is a `Some[AnotherObject]`)_, if it does not exists _(meaning it is a `None`)_, then leave it. Or, do you want to provide a default value if it is a `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `copy` on the object inside the `Option` rather than the `Option` itself, using `map`:

```
SomeObject.copy(anotherObject = SomeObject.anotherObject.map(_.copy
                            (value3 = <SomeAnotherValue>)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe, the problem is that **Option** does not have a `copy` method, whereas you would want to call the **AnotherObject** `copy` method.

Assuming, you only want to change the inner value, if your variable exists *(meaning it is a **Some**)*, then you could `map` the **Option** to get the **AnotherObject** instance.
To make it more simple for multiple calls, I created an aux method in your **SomeObject** class, to encapsulate the logic.

```
final case class AnotherObject(value1: Array[String], value2: String, value3: String)
final case class SomeObject(name: String, anotherObject: Option[AnotherObject]) {
  def changeInnerValue3(newValue: String): SomeObject =
    this.copy(
      anotherObject = this.anotherObject.map(ao => ao.copy(value3 = newValue))
    )
}

SomeObject(name = "so", anotherObject = Some(AnotherObject(value1 = Array.empty, value2 = "Hello", value3 = "World!")))
// res1: SomeObject = SomeObject(so,Some(AnotherObject([Ljava.lang.String;@52bba91a,Hello,World!)))

res1.changeInnerValue3(newValue = "You")
// res2: SomeObject = SomeObject(so,Some(AnotherObject([Ljava.lang.String;@52bba91a,Hello,You)))
```

Comment: This looks like the solution for my question, however I was looking for using copy method with map method.

Comment: @ChandramohanSawant that is what I did, did not I? What exactly do you mean?